# TypeError: Blueprint.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_folder'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

This is what my directory looks like

```
p/
  
   student/
      
      template/
               
               student/
                      
                      index.html/          
      views.py/

   __init__.py/


app.py/
```

this is what my `app.py` file looks like

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from p import app

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`__init__.py` file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 
"postgresql://postgres:1234@localhost/studentRegDB"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app, db)

from p.student.views import student_blueprints
app.register_blueprint(student_blueprints, url_prefix='/student')
```

---

`views.py` file

```
from flask import Flask, request
import psycopg2
from p import db
from p.student.forms import studentform
from p.student.models import Student
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for,redirect
from flask_blueprint import Blueprint
student_blueprints = Blueprint('student', __name__, template_folder='student')

@student_blueprints.route("/add", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def addstudent():
    form = studentform()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = request.form['name']
        course = request.form['course']
        new_student = Student(name,course)
        db.session.add(new_student)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("success.html"))
    return render_template("student.html", form=form)
```

when run the code i get the following error

student_blueprints = Blueprint('student', **name**, template_folder='student')
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Blueprint.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_folder'

**thank you for your help**

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful with names.  The package `flask_blueprint` is unrelated to the flask blueprints you get from `from flask import Blueprint`, and has completely different parameters.

I suggest you `pip uninstall flask-blueprint`, and change your code to

```
from flask import Blueprint
```